# Cannot create a new page in SPO

Tags: sharepoint-online, pages, sitepages

When selecting 'New' -> Page the page template selection popup appears normally. But when I click on create a new page, it just closes the popup, and doesn't redirect me to a the new page editor.

After investigation, the site pages feature is activated, but the 'Site Pages' library type appears to be a document library not a page library. is there anything I can do to fix the issue? it was working before and the site template is a Communication site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you recently done any changes to the site that might have caused this issue? Are you able to create new page via Site Page Library > New > Site Page?

Not much you can do here since we cannot have two Site Page Libraries in one site, so recreate the site page library is not an option.

You can try deactivating and then reactivating Site Pages feature.

Also try making another Site Page as the home page and see if it works.